# How to get rid of horizontal scroll bar in css

Tags: css

I am new to css & working on basics.So just wrote  few lines

```css
  body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0; 
                width: 100%;    
                height: 100%;      
            }
            .one {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                background-image: url("pic.jpg");
                background-size: cover;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
                position: relative;            
            } 
            
            .layer {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
            }
```

```html
            <div class="one">
                <div class="layer"></div>                     
            </div>         
            <div class="next">
                <h1>This is another para</h1>
            </div>
```

I I check it horizontal scroll bar appears. I don't know why is that & how to fix it. This is just for practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `width` of `.one` as follows:

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0; 
            width: 100%;    
            height: 100%;      
}
.one {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-image: url("pic.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            position: relative;           
} 
        
.layer {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
     <div class="layer"></div>                     
</div>         
<div class="next">
     <h1>This is another para</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man, can u please tell me what's problem in vw unit. why vw caused horizontal scroll.

Comment: Using a unit is constant for all screen sizes, this is why there's a horizantal bar showing (100 vw > screen width). Use ``%`` to take the full width.

Comment: I am really sorry for bothering u, but I've learned so far that if I've set body margin to zero, then both 100vw & 100% will work same. That's not happening here. Please just give me little description.

Comment: @BrijeshMaurya you had the explanation : width:100vw is the window's width / width:100%; is the width avalaible. so if you have a vertical scrollbar vw units won't mind it. % will

Comment: Okay I got it now, you mean vw calculates whole window dimension including scroll bar area also. I really appreciate for your time. Thanks

Comment: @BrijeshMaurya please mark the answer as the solution for future visitors facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

this problem happen because the calc using vw will consider the scrollbar size too.
To fix the problem you can use `width:100%` or `width: calc(100vw - var(--scrollbarWidth))`

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    width: 100%;    
    height: 100%;
}
.one {
    width: calc(100vw - var(--scrollbarWidth));
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/217872/pexels-photo-217872.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}         
.layer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
            <div class="layer"></div>                     
        </div>         
        <div class="next">
         <h1>This is another para</h1>
 </div>
```

I hope it can help you =)